# SoapClient could not load external entity

Tags: soap-client

Anyone could you explain the difference between the following soap options

1. `WSDL_CACHE_NONE`
2. `WSDL_CACHE_DISK`

Why I'm asking this mean, while I'm use option 1 I'm getting fatal error at the time of create a instance of `SoapClient()`, but if I use the option 2 connection was success at all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache_wsdl option is one of WSDL_CACHE_NONE, WSDL_CACHE_DISK, WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY or WSDL_CACHE_BOTH.

Refer this url for brief
http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php